# Jquery Check stylesheet and do action

Tags: jquery

me again! I'm learning a lot from this site!

Now.. i want to know how do i check with jQuery  what stylesheet i'm using and perform an action. In the case, place a favicon..

i have this script for change stylesheet on my page:

```
$("#painel_faccao li a").click(function() { 
    $("link#faccao").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));      
    $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
 return false;

});
```

and my favicon on page:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

i know i must use this:

```
$("#favicon").attr("href","favicon2.png");
```

but i don't know how to make jquery check the stylesheet..

someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check which stylesheet is used, you can check the `link href` just like you are on the favicon.

```
alert ("Your stylesheet is: " + $("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("href"));
```